# CRTP Base to Derived Conversion

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

Assume I have the following simple class hierarchy using classic inheritance:

```
struct A_classic {};
struct B_classic : A_classic {};
```

I want to implement a conversion operator from `A_classic` to `B_classic`. To reuse as much code as possible, I do

```
A_classic a; // Given as input argument
B_classic b;
static_cast<A_classic&>(b) = a; // Copy A_classic's members
// Now set up B_classic's members
```

The problem is that actually I'm using CRTP for inheritance:

```
template<class Derived> struct A_crtp_base {};
struct A_crtp : A_crtp_base<A_crtp> {};
template<class Derived> struct B_crtp_base : A_crtp_base<B_crtp_base<Derived>> {};
struct B_crtp : B_crtp_base<B_crtp> {};
```

The above trick no longer works, because the "common" base class of `A_crtp`, `B_crtp` is `A_crtp_base<A_crtp>` and `A_crtp_base<B_crtp>` respectively.

```
A_crtp a;
B_crtp b;
static_cast<A_crtp_base<???>&>(b) = a; 
// No matter what I put here, either the cast or the assignment will fail
```

An obvious solution is to template the copy constructor of `A_crtp_base`:

```
template<class Derived>
struct A_crt_base {
   template<class OtherDerived>
   A_crtp_base(const A_crtp_base<OtherDerived>& other);
}
```

But then I have to write my own copy constructor, which I would like to avoid.

Any suggestions how to minimize the amount of coding here?

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own conversion operator to the common `A_crtp_base` class

```
struct B_crtp;
template<class Derived> struct B_crtp_base;

template<class Derived>
struct A_crtp_base {

    operator B_crtp_base<B_crtp>();
};

struct A_crtp : A_crtp_base<A_crtp> {
    };

template<class Derived> struct B_crtp_base : A_crtp_base<B_crtp_base<Derived>> {};

struct B_crtp : B_crtp_base<B_crtp> {};

template<class Derived>
A_crtp_base<Derived>::operator B_crtp_base<B_crtp>()
{
        return B_crtp_base<B_crtp>(); // Whatever, make sure this is set with common A_crtp_base stuff
}

int main() 
{
   A_crtp a;
   B_crtp b;

   static_cast< B_crtp_base<B_crtp>& >(b) = a;

   return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/DLw1QK)</kbd>

A small suggestion: if possible try to simplify your hierarchy a bit, if you need a plain inheritance mechanism, you're forcing the compiler to deal with objects of different types and rendering things probably more complex than how they could be.